# "Cannot connect to the Metro server" on a React-Native / Expo project

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am currently trying to build a small thing with the MapView component using React-Native and Expo.

While the Google Map is perfectly displaying on my phone when I scan the Expo QR Code in Expo Go, I just modified my code by a tiny tiny bit, just modifying the dimensions of the map window - this might be what causes that because the way I did it is probably wrong, although I highly doubt it.

Here is my code so far (I've only used the App.js file yet):

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
 
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView style={styles.map} />
    </View>
  );
}
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window' - 10).height,
  },
});
```

The error that is displayed in my terminal is:

```
Cannot connect to the Metro server.
```

Try the following to fix the issue:

- Ensure that the Metro server is running and available on the same network
- Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices
- If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device
- If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server - e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081

URL: 10.1.5.81:19000

Comment: Does the packager run when you start the app?

Answer (score 2):

run this command in your code editor to remove the warning

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your setup, which is why the message gives you so many options. My case was the last one "Same wifi network" and I was able to solve this by setting this env var in my console to my local ip:

set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.50.112

Need to then restart expo.

No idea why Expo is using this env var for my local dev host ip, and not sure why it was set to some other ip, but it now is able to connect.